# Unable to use new Promise() in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

Expected Behavior: Able to use promises in TypeScript.

Observed Behavior: Using promises gives the following type error, 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7009)

How to duplicate the problem:
 1) Within a create react app using TypeScript try creating a promise.

```
 const test = new Promise<string>((res, _rej) => {
    res("hi");
  });
```

Comment: What is your question? This sounds more like a bug report, which should be filed in the TypeScript bug tracker.

Comment: Thank you Jörg.  It is working now without any changes on my end.   Can we delete this question?

Comment: @OlliTapio _something_ changed, you just don't know what ;)

Comment: Ha fair enough!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.resolve` instead like as below:

```
const test = Promise.resolve<string>("Hi")
```

Comment: The `<string>` is optional here, it's inferred. I double-checked to make sure

Comment: I know it's optional